# "Why is it good that..." vs. "what is good about..."

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the question *why is it good that...* and *what is good about...*? For example:

> My parents say that is good that I don't have a family yet, but **why is it good that** I don't have it yet?
>
> My parents say that is good that I don't have a family yet, but **what is good about the fact** that I don't have it yet?

If there is none, then which one sounds the most natural?

Comment: The second one sounds much more natural. I'm not sure I can explain why the first one sounds weird.

Comment: I left the above comment as an answer. It was deleted on the basis that it "does not provide an answer to the question", which, IMHO is incorrect because the question is literally "then which one sounds the most natural?" and my answer is "The second one sounds much more natural".